How do I find the IP address of devices connected through two switches?
I have a series of IP Cameras connected to switch A. Switch A is connected to switch B. Switch B is connected to a laptop that needs to access the cameras.
The cameras had static IPs set for switch A, and I can properly connect to them with a laptop connected to switch A. When connecting through switch B, those addresses no longer connect. How can I get the current addresses for the cameras from a device connected to switch B?
If it's relevant, switch A is a JetStream 8-Port Gigabit Smart Switch with 4-Port PoE+ and switch B is a Netgear Prosafe Plus Switch with PoE GS108PE. I don't think that should affect the answer, but I know very little about networking.

IPs shouldn't change between switches, but I wonder if they're smart switches, you could check on the vlan settings on each?

@JourneymanGeek I'm unsure how to do that

there should be a management IP and webUI for both. That would be a good starting point. Its a bit tricky to walk through cause every switch is different.

@JourneymanGeek one of the many issues I am having is that I am unable to access the web UI for the switches, for whatever reason. Neither one is set up to use the default IP, and I have no idea how to check what they currently are.

Have you ruled out that the switches are still working properly? For example, if you connect the camera to switch B, can you then access it from another device on switch B? And if you run an ip scan from a device on switch B, will it see other devices?

@LPChip I can access other devices through switch B, so presumably they are both working properly.
